# Adding ssh-rsa to known_hosts?

Tags: ssh

I just sent my `id_rsa.pub` to another dev to get access to a server. I received back an identical string. Did this person make a mistake and send my public key back or am I supposed to add this to `my known_hosts`?

What should I expect back in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should not receive "back" anything: that public key should be added to `~remoteUser/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the remoteServer, allowing you to do:

```
ssh remoteUSer@removeServer
```

The known_hosts will be updated upon your first connection, with the `ssh-keycan -H` fingerprint of the remote server.